# How can I generate all possible (n-length) subsets for a string?

Tags: c, recursion, set, combinations, permutation

I want to brute force attack a phase of solving the rubiks cube. I have functions like U (90 deg clockwise turn of Up dace), L, D, F2 (180 deg), B' (90 deg ccw), etc already written that simulate the rotation of all 6 faces of the cube in every possible way.

Now, I want to write a code to solve just 4 pieces ( shouldn't be more than 8 moves long). I already have it written based on a human solving method but it takes too many moves.

How can I brute force this part by testing out every possible move for n length, ie, D L2 R U is 4 moves but I want to be able to change that variable in case a certain case takes longer than 4 or 5, etc.

I tried doing recursion by testing out all possible number combinations but I wasn't close at all.

Any help/tips is appreciated.

Comment: Recursion is the way to go.  What problems did you encounter?

Comment: Are you aware there are over 40 billion, billion moves possible? But they say, max 20 are required - how much more satisfying that would be. http://www.popsci.com/science/article/2010-08/gods-number-revealed-20-moves-will-solve-any-rubiks-cube-position

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the set of faces, then loop through the rotation, and append that to your move set.  You can do it recursively as follows:

```
char faces[] = { 'U','D','L','R','F','B' };
char rotation[] = { ' ', '2', '\'' };

void move(char movestr[], int size, int count)
{
    int i, j, append;
    for (i=0;i<sizeof(faces);i++) {
        for (j=0;j<sizeof(rotation);j++) {
            append=0;
            movestr[size+(append++)] = faces[i];
            if (j != 0) movestr[size+(append++)] = rotation[i];
            movestr[size+(append++)] = ' ';
            movestr[size+append] = '\0';
            if (count > 0) {
                move(movestr, size+append, count-1);
            } else {
                // try move
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char movestr[100];
    move(movestr, 0, 4);
}
```